# How does the consensus happen in Saas based blockchain application?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

If I develop an online application using Blockchain and I have three parties(or peers) required to reach consensus then Do I need a node for each of the three participants or the one node is enough. what I am not able to understand is how I will maintain a node or nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> I will be maintaining the database at one location?

First understand that blockchain architecture is not as normal client-server architecture.

In normal client-server architecture, client can change entries that are stored on a centralized server. By changing master copy, whenever a user accesses a database, they will get the updated version.

This is not at all the same as with blockchain technology.

A blockchain is a mesh network of computers linked not to a central server but rather to each other. Computers in this network define and agree upon a shared state of data and adhere to certain constraints imposed upon this data. For a blockchain database, each participant maintains, calculates and updates new entries into the database. All nodes work together to ensure they are all coming to the same conclusions, providing in-built security for the network. Database are distributed across the participant nodes and transactions are immutable.

> How the blockchain will maintain different nodes?

Through the use of a peer-to-peer network and a distributed timestamping server, a blockchain database is managed autonomously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but If I want to have a saas application how & where the different copies of database will exist or will I have to maintain the copies of each participant?   I know my question is still very elementary but I really appreciate your patience in this.

Answer (score 0):

For a production network of three parties (in Hyperledger Fabric we use the term 'organizations') you would likely want to have a network of multiple (2 or more) peer nodes per organization for crash tolerance and increased resilience. You would also likely want to run these peer nodes on different host nodes in different data centers or cloud availability zones.